# How can I force all the windows to the fore when I alt-tab into any one of them?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm creating a GUI app in QT5 using c++. I want to make it so that, assuming all of the windows are not at the fore (say, I've alt-tabbed to a different application or they're all minimized), if I alt-tab into any one of the several windows of my app, then they should all come to the fore and be visible.

Comment: The way you describe it, it seems to go directly against how systems work and what users expect. Why do you want to do this? Perhaps there's a good way of solving *that* problem.

Comment: Well, my app has a main window to display the parameters sent by an FPGA (over serial communication using modbus if you're interested), and then based ,on what the user chooses, I open secondary windows to display things such as graphs or tables, and I would like all of them to be visible simultaneously without the user having to bring them into the fore one by one; I've already figured out how to position them so that they don't visually overlap.

Comment: That seems like a case where [MDI](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-mdi-example.html) or [dock widgets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-dockwidgets-example.html) might fit and would avoid the problem entirely.

Comment: Set the main window as parent of the other windows.

Comment: I'm creating the other windows dynamically within my 'main' window; is that what you mean by parent or is there something more I need to do?

Comment: I had a look into our software (where all dialogs are popped together with main window on activation with Alt+Tab). I saw that we use [`QWidget::setParent(QWidget*, Qt::WindowsFlags)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setParent-1) for the dialogs. Thereby, the 1st argument is the main window, the 2nd `Qt::Dialog`. I cannot tell you why we need the 2nd arg and whether it would work as well if we had used instead [`QWidget::setParent(QWidget*)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setParent).

Comment: how do I reference the pointer for the main window? would it simply be ui? I tried changing main.cpp's [MainWin w; w.show();] to MainWin* *w = new MainWin; w->show()] and then (again in main.cpp) passed w to a public function with a single parameter of type MainWin*, and that public function assigned it to internal member of type MainWin*, which I then used for QWidget::setParent. But that didn't work =(

Comment: @hvd I checked out both and it seems like I'd need to drastically modify my code to implement those, so I'll try it if a simpler solution doesn't present itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key-term is "transient window". I found this (for me appropriate) explanation on Wikipedia [Transient (computer programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient_(computer_programming))

> In the [X Window System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System), a window is said to be transient for another window if it belongs to that other window and may not outlast it: a dialog box, such as an alert message, is a common example.

IMHO, this is not limited to the X11.

In Qt, a dialog becomes transient if its parent is set to another window.

I made a small sample:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version: " << QT_VERSION_STR;
  // main application
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QWidget qWin;
  QVBoxLayout qVBoxWin;
  QLabel qLblWin(QString::fromUtf8("Main Window (QWidget)"));
  qVBoxWin.addWidget(&qLblWin, 1);
  qWin.setLayout(&qVBoxWin);
  qWin.show();
#define MAKE_DIALOG(I) \
  QDialog qDlg##I; \
  qDlg##I.setWindowTitle(QString::fromUtf8("Dialog"#I)); \
  QVBoxLayout qVBoxDlg##I; \
  QLabel qLblDlg##I(QString::fromUtf8("Dialog"#I" (QDialog)")); \
  qVBoxDlg##I.addWidget(&qLblDlg##I, 1); \
  qDlg##I.setLayout(&qVBoxDlg##I)
  // dialog 1 without parent
  MAKE_DIALOG(1);
  // dialog 2 with parent
  MAKE_DIALOG(2);
  qDlg2.setParent(&qWin, Qt::Dialog);
#undef MAKE_DIALOG
  qWin.show();
  qDlg1.show();
  qDlg2.show();
  // run-time loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Compiled and tested with VS2013 and Qt 5.9.2 on Windows 10 (64 bit):

[image: snapshot of testQMainWin-Dlgs]

The application consists of a main window (`qWin`) and two dialog windows (`qDlg1` and `qDlg2`).

[image: appearance of testQMainWin-Dlgs in the Windows 10 taskbar]

The dialog 1 (`qDlg1` which has no parent widget) appears as separate entry (beside of the main window) in the Windows 10 task bar. The dialog 2 (`qDlg2`) is transient and does not appear.

[image: snapshot of testQMainWin-Dlgs after Alt+Tab]

The dialog 1 can be chosen separately in the task choice (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>). Choosing the main window, the main window and dialog 2 are brought on top. Thereby, dialog 2 is always on top of the main window.

*Note:*

I was not sure whether the 2<sup>nd</sup> argument `Qt::Dialog` in `qDlg2.setParent(&qWin, Qt::Dialog);` is necessary. It seems it is. (When I left it out, the dialog 2 became not visible at all.)

Comment: Works for me, thanks a lot! Not just for the answer, but also its thoroughness